# How likely will Tom's bag be heavier than Sally's bag?

Tags: algorithm, probability, combinatorics

Tom and Sally each have 50 cantaloupes that each weigh integer values from 0 to 1500 ounces inclusive. They each randomly bag 20 of their own cantaloupes. What's the probability that Tom's bag weighs at least 1.5 that of Sally's given the weights of all 100 canteloupes?

I modeled this question as a function that takes as input two int arrays each of size 50 and returns a double from 0 to 1. I tried to list all combinations of size 20 for the values in the arrays and then, for each combination of Tom's weights, loop through all of Sally's combinations and count how many are less than 1.5 times Tom's bag weight. However, this method has proven way too slow.

Is there a faster way? Or am I resigned to this I believe exponential method.

Comment: How good a result do you need? Can you use approximations or simulations?

Comment: I need exact, so I don't think I can do something like a Monte Carlo method. :/

Comment: This problem seems very difficult to solve exactly. Perhaps even [#P-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp-P-complete), though it may well be easier than that.

Comment: What do you need to do with the solution?

Comment: Hmm, ideally within a second in say javascript or php.

Comment: You don't specify the distribution of weights of Tom and Sally's cantaloupes. Is it assumed that they're iid uniform(0, 1500)?

Comment: @DavidFaux: Sorry, I meant what goal do you need to achieve using this solution, not what runtime do you need the solution to achieve.

Comment: I actually don't know the distribution. The weights are given as input. My purpose is to make a web app that computes this info for some inputs that the user specifies.

Comment: Unless you have some other feature you can exploit, I doubt that you can solve this problem optimally with some kind of heuristic due to the randomization of the items.

Comment: hmm, can we exploit how the weights are integers somehow?

Comment: Other than having a finite range, I cannot think of any other feature that you can exploit. Maybe you could have more luck on the `Mathematics` stack exchange?

Comment: A pure mathematical solution would only work if you only work with probabilities and distribution. The fact that the actual weights of the cantaloupes will be given as input, and thus not necessarily follow any random distribution, you're left with algorithmically working out the answer. What kind of web app would this be? What kind of problems would it solve for who? However, I'm no stat/math wiz so my advice too would be to ask a mathematician or statistician first.

Comment: I want to see a 1,500 ounce (94 pound) cantaloupe.

Comment: You can use [Chebyshev's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev's_inequality#Asymmetric_two-sided_case) to find the expected value of a lower bound on the probability; you'll be computing P(1.5S < T < M), where `S` and `T` are random variables representing the weight of Sally's and Tom's choices, respectively, and M is the weight of Tom's 20 heaviest cantaloupes. The resulting lower bound is a function of `S`, so you can take the expectation of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since C(50,20) = 47,129,212,243,960, but 1500x20 = 30,000,
it would be more useful to build two arrays (for Tom and for Sally), each of size 30,000, and count in each index *i* the number of combinations (out of the total C(50,20) combinations) with total weight *i*.

Comparing the probabilities of S(Sally)<1.5*S(Tom) using such arrays is a manageable task.

The main question is can we build such arrays faster than calculating the 47,129,212,243,960 sums? In other words - can we find out effectively how many subsets of size 20 sum up to any of the 30,000 possible values?

A dynamic programming approach to the subset-sum problem is very practical in this case, as it requires only 50 * 20 * 1500 arithmetic operations.

Comment: You found a reduction from subset sum to this? I tried, but I couldn't come up with one. How'd you do it?

Comment: @user2357112: If we call find how many subsets of size n sum up to s in O(p), then we can solve the subst-sum polynomially as well - in O(n*p) - trying for subsets of size 1..n Remeber that the subset-sum is a decision problem.

Comment: Yep, that was easy. I need (needed and still need) to go to bed.

Answer (score 2):

Fun with generating functions: let t_i be the weight of Tom's ith cantaloupe and s_i be the weight of Sally's ith cantaloupe. Compute polynomials T(x, y) = product_i (1 + x y^t_i) and S(x, y) = product_i (1 + x y^s_i). The coefficient of x^k y^w is the number of ways to choose k cantaloupes with total weight w. Let T20(y) be the coefficient of x^20 in T(x, y) and S20(y) be the coefficient of x^20 in T(x, y). Compute the product T(y^2) S(y^-3). The coefficient of y^delta is the number of ways Tom's weight minus 1.5 times Sally's weight equals 0.5 delta. Return the sum of coefficients for nonnegative powers of y divided by the sum of coefficients for all powers of y.

This is only weakly polynomial in the total cantaloupe weight, but that seems to be good enough here.

Comment: I'm not sure I get it. What is the big-O time complexity?

Comment: @LiorKogan If it's n choose k with maximum weight W, then we're talking about O(n k^2 W) arithmetic operations on O(n)-bit values for naive polynomial multiplication.